# tensorflow LinearClassifier predict function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I've been playing around with tensorflow and because of lack of documentation I'm having a lot of troubles to understand some of the function outputs.

In this case, for the module **tf.estimator.LinearClassifier** I don't understand what the parameters in the dictionary returned by the function **predict()** mean. Below there's an example:

> {'probabilities': array([0.92966837, 0.07033166], dtype=float32),
>   'logits': array([-2.581606], dtype=float32), 'classes': array(['0'],
>   dtype=object), 'class_ids': array([0]), 'logistic':
>   array([0.07033166], dtype=float32)}

I assume that the array "probabilities" contains = [1-p, p], where "p" is the probability and I understand the "classes" and "class_ids" meaning.

However I get lost with the other dict keys. Can someone point me to some good documentation where the outputs of functions are explained?

Thanks!